# Which formula should I use to know which numbers sum will come out my exact result in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, worksheet-function

On the image below I have these numbers.

Now I want to know which numbers sum will come out with the result of 98541.03. How do I find that?

[image: Result]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! I don't understand why you highlighted some cells in yellow? They are irrelevant to the desired result. What you actually need is the 16th and 20th cell: `23591.62 + 74949.41 = 98541.03`

Comment: Sir, Your answer is correct but i just want to know what formula i can use to find that result in M.S. Excel

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, what, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What research have you done? These optimization questions appear about every 6 months and the aswer is always the same. You can try solver, but it may only give youi one solution (if any). You can try a brute force method with VBA, but the time it takes exponentially expands with each number added.

Comment: The `findSet()` function, which solves such problems, was introduced in ["Looking for math function for finding the highest possibile sum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887738/looking-for-math-function-for-finding-highest-possibile-sum). Yes, for this to work in Excel, you will have to make a few changes to the code - get values from the range, describe the optional parameter. Or start using LibreOffice. *(At least we will know that you did something yourself)*

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to brute force it: calculate every possible SUM combination and find the matching set.

If you have *N* values, you'll have *2^N* possible solutions. The idea is to use binary representation to reduce the maths required. Lets say each row is assigned one bit of an integer number e.g. 1001 means sum value 1 and value 4. So now, in a new sheet number values in column A from 0 to (2^*N*)-1 in decimal. If you add a column in B with `=BASE(A1,2,N)`, this will give the binary representation of each sum to be calculated for each possible combination. In the next column (C) put

```
=SUMPRODUCT(data,--MID(B1,N-ROW(data)+ROW(INDEX(data,1)),1))
```

Where *data* is say *sheet1!A1:A100* with the source values and thus *N* is `=ROWS(data)`. This is an array formula and must be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in versions of Excel prior to 365. It takes a sum combination value and converts it to binary (as a text string of zeros and ones). This string is converted to an array *{"0"; "1"; ...}* of text using MID with an array *{N; N-1; ...; 2; 1}* input variable derived from the data vector's reference address. The string array is converted to numbers with *--* as in minus minus, and then finally SUMPRODUCT-ed to calculate the sum for that combination.

In column D, search for the matching combination, and propagate it upwards, so that it is visible in the top row (assuming there is only one unique solution):

```
=IF(C1=98541.03,B1,C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Excel "Solver" functionality to do this for you, but it is not a formula, rather it is a wizard you run that manually run each time you want to find the numbers that sum.  I'll create a very small sample here to demonstrate and then you just scale the ranges up.

**1. Prerequisites**

- You have to have the solver add-in turned on in excel
- You have to be OK creating a helper column somewhere.  It can be hidden elsewhere, even on a different sheet inside the workbook.  Just has to have the same number of rows as your data column.

**2. Add a column to your data or elsewhere**

Say this is A1:B7:

| Value | Found It |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 400 | 1 |
| 600 | 1 |
| 225 | 1 |
| 409 | 1 |
| 625 | 1 |

**3. Set up info for the Solver**

- Go to cell D1 and enter `=sumproduct(A2:A7,B2:B7)`.  The cell will now contain the sum of all A values.
- Go to cell D2 and enter the sum you want to find.  Let's say for this sample data you enter `809`.
- Go do cell D3 and enter `=D1-D2`.  This cell is the difference between the sum and the sought goal of 809.

**4. Logic Explanation**

We will tell the solver to trial-and-error combinations of 1s and 0s in each cell in Column B.  SUMPRODUCT multiplies each value with its associated 1 or 0.  So in this case D1 will contain the sum of all values that have a 1 next to them and ignore any value with a 0 next to it.

So let the solver try all possible combinations of 1s and 0s for you.

**5. Run the Solver**

- Set the `objective` to be D3.
- Set `To:` to be `Value OF:` `0`
- Set `By Changing Variable Cells` to be `$A$2:$B$7` for my sample data--adjust to yours
- Add a `Subject to the Constraints` entry: `$A$2:$B$7`, and make the middle field `bin`.  The constraint field should be `binary`.
- Click `Solve`
- If it finds a matching combination, select `Keep Solver Solution` and click `OK`
- Values in column A will be unchanged.  Only values that added up to the goal will now have a 1 in coumn B, all others will be 0.

**6. Conclusion**
This takes a minute to set up the first time, after that you will be able to check any sum in seconds.  Place the new desired sum in D2 and run the solver.